# How to show frequency of elements in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame containing the following columns (with an existing numeric index):

```
    points | variety
    ----------------
1       97 | Chardonnay
17      67 | Cabernet Sauvignon
12      70 | Cabernet Sauvignon
8       97 | Chardonnay
```

I would like to transform this into a new DataFrame with:

- The `points` column as the new index
- One column for each unique entry in the `variety` column
- The values in the new variety-named columns to contain the frequency with which each variety occurred for the original `points` value in the original table.

E.g. from the example above:

```
    Chardonnay | Cabernet Sauvignon
    -------------------------------
97           2 | 0
67           0 | 1
70           0 | 1
```

Notice the original index is not relevant to the output. Here is an image showing a more complete example: [Pandas DataFrame Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW7JN.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) for this:

```
pd.crosstab(index=df.points, columns=df.variety)
```

[out]

```
variety  Cabernet Sauvignon  Chardonnay
points                                 
67                        1           0
70                        1           0
97                        0           2
```